# Nudges asked for The Stone 3:3 : The Waiting?

Tags: the-stone

I have 3 closes on 3:3 the Waiting. I think I know what the puzzle is about but I can't seem to find it. I tried various combinations but I can't seem to get it right.

I found this: http://www.scarecrowsfield.com --> The Immediate -> 3:3.

p.s. / update on an update: to follow the stone tradition: please do NOT give direct solutions to these puzzles but hints to the answser, the "nudges" in stone terminology. The game system forbids given direct answers. The fun is in the journey not the goal.

Nonetheless: any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*An unexpected event sometimes attributed to a divine entity* should lead you to the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Teryx, I'm going to spend my evening thinking about this one. Really appreciate your help

Comment: then again... i think that unexpected event is one of the three closes i already have LOL but it means... im close :)

Comment: solved! Wow. this one was really good!